# Bernstein-Zelevinsky classification: viewing a representation as a subrepresentation or a quotient

Tags: representation-theory, reductive-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ind}{Ind}$I have a question on the details of the Bernstein-Zelevinsky classification.  This classification allows us to obtain irreducible representations of $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ over a $p$-adic field $F$ as unique quotients of certain induced representations coming from supercuspidals, in an essentially unique way.

It also allows us to obtain these representations as unique subrepresentations in an essentially unique way.

Suppose $\pi$ is a smooth irreducible representation of $\GL_n(F)$, and we know how to obtain $\pi$ as a quotient $Q(\Delta_1, ... , \Delta_r)$ in the B.Z. classification.  Then do we also know how to obtain $\pi$ as a subrepresentation $Z(\Delta_1', ... , \Delta_{r'}')$ in B.Z. classification?

Example: suppose $G = \operatorname{GL}_2(F)$, and $\chi = \chi_1$ is a character of $F^{\ast}$, $\chi_2(x) = \chi_1(x)|x|_F$.  Then $\Ind_{TU}^G \chi_1 \otimes \chi_2$ has a unique irreducible quotient $\pi$.  If we want to get $\pi$ as subrepresentation instead of a quotient, then we swap $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ and use $\Ind_{TU}^G \chi_2 \otimes \chi_1$.

Comment: Can you remind me how $Z(\cdots)$ is related to $Q(\cdots)$? I feel like this problem is hard, but maybe is answered in http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0107.5052. See this paper for connections with your question: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0011.5074

Comment: Thank you.  If $\Delta$ is a sequence $(\pi, \pi(1), ...)$, then $Z(\Delta)$ is the unique irreducible subrepresentation of $\operatorname{Ind} \pi \otimes \pi(1) \cdots$ and $Q(\Delta)$ is its unique irreducible quotient.